# Python 3, bs4, webcrawler; error connecting too website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to build a web-crawler for a specific website.
But for some reason I won't connect to the website.
I get a error (made myself) it can't connect. 
Using selesium tot call up the website, I see it doesn't connect

As a newbie I am probably making a stupid mistake but I can't figure out what. 
Hoping you are willing to help me.

```
import csv
import requests
import datetime
from time import sleep, time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/907133/Pythonstuff/chromedriver')
browser.set_window_position(0,0)
captcha = input('Press Enter after bypassing Captcha')

# def get_driver():
#     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#     return driver


def get_driver():
    # initialize options
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # pass in headless argument to options
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    # initialize driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    return driver


def connect_to_base(browser, page_number):
    base_url = f'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{page_number}'
    html = None
    links = None
    connection_attempts = 0
    while connection_attempts < 3:
        try:
            browser.get(base_url)
            #wait for table element with id = 'map' to load
            #before returning True
            WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'result-content')))
            return True
        except Exception as ex:
            connection_attempts += 1
            print(f'Error connecting to {base_url}')
            print(f'Attempt #{connection_attempts}')
    return False


def parse_html(html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        inside = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'property-inner'},{'href'})
        # Make empty lists with header lines
        output_list = []
        listing = 1
        for items in inside:
            href = items.get('href')
            url1 = href.format(page)    
        if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='CookiesOK']"))>0:
                browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='CookiesOK']").click()
        connection_attempts = 0
        while connection_attempts < 3:
            try:
                browser.get(url1)
                WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'detail-address')))
                return True
            except Exception as ex:
                connection_attempts += 1
                print(f'Error connecting to {base_url}')
                print(f'Attempt #{connection_attempts}')

            details = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html')       
            adres = details.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-address'})
            for adresinfo in adres:
                try:
                    adres = adres[0].get_text(separator=',', strip=True)
                except Indexerror:
                    adres = "Unknown"

            kenmerken = details.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-tab-content kenmerken'})
            try:
                tr_kenmerken = ','.join([td.text.strip() for td in kenmerken[0].select('td.value')])
            except IndexError:
                tr_kenmerken = 'Unknown'

            waarde = details.find_all ('div', {'class':'detail-tab-content woningwaarde'})
            try:
                tr_waarde = ','.join([td.text.strip() for td in waarde[0].select('td.value')])
            except IndexError:
                tr_waarde = 'Unknown'

            informatie = {
                'adres': adres, 
                'kenmerken': tr_kenmerken,
                'waarde': tr_waarde, 
                'url': href
            }

            output_list.append(informatie)
            listing += 1
        return output_list


def get_load_time(article_url):
    try:
        # set headers
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
        # make get request to article_url
        response = requests.get(
            article_url, headers=headers, stream=True, timeout=3.000)
        # get page load time
        load_time = response.elapsed.total_seconds()
    except Exception as ex:
        load_time = 'Loading Error'
    return load_time


def write_to_file(output_list, filename):
    for row in output_list:
        with open(filename, 'a') as csvfile:
            fieldnames = ['adres', 'kenmerken', 'waarde', 'link']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writerow(row)


def run_process(page_number, filename, browser):
    if connect_to_base(browser, page_number):
        sleep(2)
        html = browser.page_source
        output_list = parse_html(html)
        write_to_file(output_list, filename)
    else:
        print('Error connecting to jaap')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set variables
    start_time = time()
    current_page = 1
    output_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    output_filename = f'output_{output_timestamp}.csv'
    browser = get_driver()
    # scrape and crawl
    while current_page <= 3:
        print(f'Scraping page #{current_page}...')
        run_process(current_page, output_filename, browser)
        current_page = current_page + 1
    # exit
    browser.quit()
    end_time = time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f'Elapsed run time: {elapsed_time} seconds')
```

Comment: don't swallow the exception... at least print it it so you know what the error occurring is.

Comment: File "<ipython-input-9-ce902ae2fb40>", line 45
         def run_process(page_number, filename, browser):
                                                                                          ^
         IndentationError: unexpected unindent


i get the following error

Comment: Yeah i am trying to figure out what the mistake is i made, but can't find it.
any suggestions as possible mistakes?

Comment: Where is the definition of this two function `parse_html()` and `write_to_file()`

Comment: You have `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,{'class':'result-content'}))`, but then want it by class?? should be: `WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'result-content')))`. Then, as stated above, where's your functions to `parse_html()` and `write_to_file()`?

Comment: I left those out of the code because i thought they where not relevant to the answer.
i updated the code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you fixed `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,{'class':'result-content'}))` to be `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'result-content')))`

Next, you might have an issue with (depending where the browser is opened) of having to bypass/clicking a javascript that says you are ok and accept cookies.

But all that code seems to be an awful lot of work considering the data is stored as a json format in the `script` tags from the html. Why not just simply use `requests`, pull out the json, convert to dataframe, then write to csv?

```
import requests
import datetime
from time import sleep, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def run_process(page_number):
    base_url = f'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{page_number}'
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    jsonStr = soup.find('script', {'id':'page-data'}).text
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

    df = json_normalize(jsonData['properties'])
    return df



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set variables
    start_time = time()
    current_page = 1
    output_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    output_filename = f'C:/test/output_{output_timestamp}.csv'

    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    while current_page <= 3:
        print(f'Scraping page #{current_page}...')
        df = run_process(current_page)
        final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
        current_page = current_page + 1
    final_df.to_csv(output_filename, index=False)
    end_time = time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f'Elapsed run time: {elapsed_time} seconds')
```

**Output:**

```
Scraping page #1...
Scraping page #2...
Scraping page #3...
Elapsed run time: 7.441420555114746 seconds
```

and the csv file that looks like:

```
     app area                                         detailsUrl  expired       houseTypeValue        id  latLng  latLng.latitude  latLng.longitude location.city               location.street location.zipcode   lotSize market numberOfRooms openHouseDate openHouseTimes  openhouse                             photo      price  priceToShow showoffColor showoffCustomText showoffPhotoText  spotlight             status  veiling
0  False  165  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False            Herenhuis   6899666     NaN        52.368420          4.833631     AMSTERDAM         Hof van Versailles 61           1064NX       216   sale             4          None           None      False  10014EAAF8B8883668593EFAC9E5FF1C   595000.0     595000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
1   True  211  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False          Appartement  10585731     NaN        52.327550          4.889076     AMSTERDAM                Beysterveld 35           1083KA  Onbekend   sale             4          None           None      False  E4F9E5BC7BC90B5B92C7BD8D48B7A677   925000.0     925000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
2   True  111  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False  Dubbele bovenwoning  11731386     NaN        52.341890          4.896053     AMSTERDAM      Uiterwaardenstraat 320 2           1079DC  Onbekend   sale             5          None           None      False  AB9F45B2CD4AD7879C5A80F18092F9D4   750000.0     750000.0         None              None             None      False  SoldConditionally    False
3  False  269  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False            Herenhuis  11840681     NaN        52.358266          4.875508     AMSTERDAM      Korte van Eeghenstraat 4           1071ER       107   sale             9          None           None      False  A3DF2B1D426B5E4D501503C5D0E66966  3100000.0    3100000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
4  False  100  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False         Tussenwoning  12152943     NaN        52.421245          4.899478     AMSTERDAM  Pieter A v Heijningestraat 9           1035SV        83   sale             5          None           None      False  55C6F589523FA553D67A709776DD70DD   399000.0     399000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
5   True  111  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False          Bovenwoning  15796874     NaN              NaN               NaN     AMSTERDAM      Eerste Amstelvlietpad 20           1096GB  Onbekend   sale             3          None           None      False  AE822B627ED096310B9ECBE7756340C8  1200000.0    1200000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
6   True   76  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False        Benedenwoning  10580650     NaN        52.346010          4.888799     AMSTERDAM       Grevelingenstraat 18 HS           1078KP  Onbekend   sale             2          None           None      False  6FD1011D917E776DCF4DA836B5FFEE3E   550000.0     550000.0         None              None             None      False  SoldConditionally    False
7  False  298  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False                Villa   9623182     NaN        52.330610          4.862902     AMSTERDAM                 Cannenburg 51           1081GW       651   sale             7          None           None      False  15FA170B99D4E2DEA03B6FC27E3B5B74  2495000.0    2495000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
8  False  270  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False            Herenhuis  15791215     NaN        52.347780          5.004530     AMSTERDAM            Nico Jessekade 189           1087MR       200   sale             9          None           None      False  6EA5C0CDA0475DFC88A3A918A6B2909A  1549000.0    1549000.0         None              None             None      False  SoldConditionally    False
9  False  201  /te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterd...    False                Villa   9617942     NaN        52.377391          4.764554     AMSTERDAM               Osdorperweg 803           1067SW      1348   sale             6          None           None      False  4680429D99EC5AC47C950D57A77DF1EB   950000.0     950000.0         None              None             None      False               Sale    False
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import requests
import datetime
from time import sleep, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np

def run_process(page_number):
    page_number = 1
    base_url = f'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p{page_number}'
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    jsonStr = soup.find('script', {'id':'page-data'}).text
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)


    df = json_normalize(jsonData['properties'])
    root_URL = 'https://jaap.nl'
    df['detailsUrl'] = root_URL + df['detailsUrl']

    allPropDetails = pd.DataFrame()


    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        propDetails = pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
        w=1
        detailLink = row['detailsUrl']
        print ('Scraping: %s' %(row['location.street']))
        dfs = pd.read_html(detailLink)

        for each in dfs:

            #each = dfs[8]
            w=1
            if each.isnull().all().all():
                continue
            each = each.dropna(axis=0, how='all')

            specialCase = False
            for col in list(each.columns):
                if each[col].dtypes == 'object':
                    if each[col].str.contains('Voorziening').any():
                        specialCase = True
                        break

            if specialCase == True:
                df_obj = each.select_dtypes(['object'])
                each[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('. '))
                cols1 = list(each.iloc[2:,0])
                each = each.iloc[2:,:]
                each[1] = each[1] + '---' + each[2]
                each = each.iloc[:,-2]
                each.index = cols1

                each = each.to_frame().T
                propRow = each
                propRow.index = [0]

                temp_df = pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
                for col in propRow.columns:
                    temp_df = temp_df.merge(propRow[col].str.split('---', expand=True).rename(columns={0:col, 1:col+'.distance'}),left_index=True, right_index=True )
                propRow = temp_df


            else:
                df_obj = each.select_dtypes(['object'])
                each[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('. '))

                temp_df = each.T
                cols = [ temp_df.index[0] + '_' + colName for colName in list(temp_df.iloc[0,:]) ]

                propRow = temp_df.iloc[-1,:]
                propRow.index = cols
                propRow = propRow.to_frame().T
                propRow.index = [0]

            propDetails = propDetails.merge(propRow, left_index=True, right_index=True)


        propDetails.index = [idx]    
        allPropDetails = allPropDetails.append(propDetails, sort=True)

    df = df.merge(allPropDetails, how = 'left', left_index=True, right_index=True)        
    return df



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set variables
    start_time = time()
    current_page = 1
    output_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    output_filename = f'C:/test/output_{output_timestamp}.csv'

    final_df = pd.DataFrame()
    while current_page <= 3:
        print(f'Scraping page #{current_page}...')
        df = run_process(current_page)
        final_df = final_df.append(df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
        current_page = current_page + 1
    final_df.to_csv(output_filename, index=False)
    end_time = time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f'Elapsed run time: {elapsed_time} seconds')
```

Comment: Thanks this works indeed a bit faster!

only i also need information inside the listing like size of the house and so on.
that's why the code is so complicated. is there a way with this method to also crawl with the Href inside the link and get those details

Comment: yes. Give me a few minutes. It could be in the json (that I haven't normalized). Or You do have a column of the detailsUrl. Would then just be a matter of iterating through those. Like I said, give me a few minutes to work that out

Comment: @Lex876, do you mean that data/tables when you click to get the property details? Like: `Woninggegevens`, `Energie`, etc?

Comment: yes i try to get those, they on the second page under the description
https://www.jaap.nl/te-koop/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/1064nx/hof+van+versailles+61/6899666/overzicht?search=/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam/p1

Comment: yes i mean those, some are "hard data" (mostly up) and some are calculate data (dutch statistics) based on the "hard data" (mostly down)

Comment: @Lex876, YUP! Ok got it. Little trickier, but can be done. I'll have it for you in a bit

Comment: @Lex876, updated it. It's a little clunky. Took about 2.5 minutes to run through 3 pages, but looks like I managed to get all those tables into 1 table

Comment: Tanks a lot! This helps. 
I'll make it my next challenge to implement multiprocessing in the code

Comment: @Lex876, when you get that to work, do you mind sharing it with me. I'd be interested in seeing that (I need to learn how that's done as well!)